# Reserved JavaScript

Tags: code-challenge, javascript

As of ECMAScript 2015, JavaScript has [33 reserved keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords), such as `break`, `const` and `new`, as well as [10 future reserved keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Future_reserved_keywords), such as `let` and `await`.

Your task is to chain together the largest number of consecutive<sup>1</sup> distinct reserved keywords<sup>2</sup> while writing functional JavaScript code<sup>3</sup>.

1. Consecutive reserved keywords - reserved keywords that are separated only by whitespace and/or parentheses and/or curly braces.
2. Reserved keywords - any [reserved or future reserved keywords as of ECMAScript 2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords). Reserved keywords from older standards are excluded, a full list of allowed keywords is given below.
3. Functional code - your code should run (state your runtime, if necessary), eventually halt, and not throw any runtime errors.

If your code needs a specific runtime, the used reserved keywords must not be no-ops in the given environment.

### List of reserved keywords

```html
await
break
case
catch
class
const
continue
debugger
default
delete
do
else
enum
export
extends
finally
for
function
if
implements
import
in
instanceof
interface
let
new
package
private
protected
public
return
static
super
switch
this
throw
try
typeof
var
void
while
with
yield
```

### Scoring & examples

Your score will be equal to the largest number of consecutive distinct reserved keywords.
In the case of equal scores, shortest source code in bytes wins. Commented sections and strings don't count towards reserved keywords, but count towards byte count.

```js
// score: 3
if (true) 0; else throw function() {}
             ^------------------^
// score: 2
let foo = typeof typeof void typeof void 0;
                             ^---------^
// score: 0
/* typeof default debugger */

// score: 0, doesn't halt or debugger is no-op, depending on the environment
debugger;
```

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

Comment: [Sandbox discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16099/16484), for those who are interested.

Comment: I feel like this might be more interesting if you did not allow parentheses between the keywords.

Comment: Is newline allowed?

Comment: @l4m2 Yes, it's whitespace.

Comment: Now that 43-score solution exist...

Comment: @l4m2 The same 43-point solution is possible without newlines as well so perhaps I simply don't understand the point you're trying to make?

Comment: `In the case of equal scores, shortest source code in bytes wins.` The common solution uses 4 extra chars for each word but sometimes it can do better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75492/discussion-between-l4m2-and-nit).

Comment: @msh210 Thanks, I didn't know tags are used like that on PCG, updated.

Answer (score 58):

## 43 words, 603 bytes

Uhm, is this a loophole? I have no idea how the hell this is legal JS, but it works and it uses every single keyword.

```js
new (class await
{
    break(){}
    case(){}
    catch(){}
    const(){}
    continue(){}
    debugger(){}
    default(){}
    delete(){}
    do(){}
    else(){}
    enum(){}
    export(){}
    extends(){}
    finally(){}
    for(){}
    function(){}
    if(){}
    implements(){}
    import(){}
    in(){}
    instanceof(){}
    interface(){}
    let(){}
    package(){}
    private(){}
    protected(){}
    public(){}
    return(){}
    static(){}
    super(){}
    switch(){}
    this(){}
    throw(){}
    try(){}
    typeof(){}
    var(){}
    void(){}
    while(){}
    with(){}
    yield(){}
})
```

Comment: Not that familiar with JS, but... are these actually *keywords* when used in this context, or just strings that have the same lexical structure as keywords and are using sugar to avoid quotes?

Comment: @Leushenko  Probably the second (although I'm also not too familiar with JS at all), as they look like function names in the way they are used. Still, normally it shouldn't be possible to use these keywords as functions or class names, but _Siguza_ still did it, while still complying to the challenge rules of only using parenthesis and brackets. A nice find to complete this challenge with all words I'd say, even though most of the other answers look more impressive for actually using the keywords AS *keywords*. Still +1 from me, it seems we have a winner.

Comment: Of course you can make the answer more interesting by moving some of the keywords into the function body. Why not?

Comment: @user202729 Why though? Why make it overly complexly looking when it can be done so simple? Code-golfing is usually doing something as short as possible, but I personally still prefer to keep readability and simplicity to some extend (I know, I know, this isn't a code-golfing challenge). Some examples: I prefer to use `-1`, `i+1`, `i-1` above `~0`, `-~i`, `~-i` when I can, just because it's clearer to read for those who aren't too familiar with code-golfing and `~` yet. Although I will of course always use `i+~j` and `i-~j` to golf that single byte of `i-j-1` and `i+j+1`. ;)

Comment: Yes, I could mash it further, and try to get the byte count down... a beginning like `if(this)return void typeof function(){} else debugger` isn't hard to come up with, but after that it gets ugly fast. And yes, this totally turns keywords into identifiers - but for some of them you _have_ to in order to be able to use them (e.g. `enum`). I just took it to the extreme, but isn't that what code golfing is all about? :P

Comment: Are you... literally redefining the function of keywords?

Comment: @Magic No, supplying the name of a class-method is simply a grammatical context where literal tokens are treated as property names, even if they are reserved words. This is basically the same, semantically, as doing `obj["break"] = function (){}` etc.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Because not attempting further golfing means this one   actually loses, as ties are broken by bytecount.

Comment: Save tons of bytes: Eliminate the leading spaces in front of each line

Answer (score 57):

## 37 words

```js
if (void this) {
  do {
    with (protected)
      for (public in private)
        typeof static instanceof new (function implements() {
          var let
          try {
            throw (class extends {} {})
          } catch (package) {
            yield
          } finally {
            debugger
          }
          return
        })()
    continue
    break
  } while (interface)
} else {
  switch (delete await) { default : 42 }
}
```

Keywords not used:

- `case` requires `:`
- `const` requires `=`
- `export` requires strict mode
- `import` requires strict mode
- `super` requires `constructor`

Comment: I admit I laughed

Comment: It looks like typical Java boilerplate code, e.g. to calculate `1 + 2`.

Comment: @EricDuminil This is the real reason it's called _Java_​Script.

Comment: This is just wonderful.

Comment: @apsillers that's not a dumb thing to do at all. In fact it's preferable to using `let` or `var`. Remember that `const` and `let` have more reasonable scoping than `var`; the variable defined is scoped to the loop body, not the function, so if it stays constant within an iteration, then `const` is fine.

Comment: @Dave Yeah, I realized that I was wrong today when I was running my entry -- a `const` loop var is usually very good practice

Answer (score 35):

## 43 words, <s>302</s> 299 bytes

```js
switch(void function(){for(const interface in public)do with(package)try{break}catch(private){if(typeof
this)throw yield static instanceof new class extends await{case(){return}super(){debugger}import(){}export(){}enum(){}}
else continue}finally{delete let}while(protected)var implements}){default:}
```

Comment: Theoretical lowerbound 277 (each two words separated by one byte)

Comment: Nice work, currently you're only missing `enum`.

Answer (score 10):

## <s>21</s> <s>24</s> 26 words, 185 bytes

*+<s>1</s> 2 words thanks to Arnauld, and +1 to 12Me21!*

```js
void(function(){do{with({})if(typeof true in this)throw{}instanceof new(class extends{}{})
else return delete{}
try{break}finally{yield}
continue
}while(false)})()
switch({}){case{}:{}}
```

Assuming I understood the challenge, this scores 24 words. The words without parentheses, brackets, and whitespace:

```js
void function do with if typeof true in this throw instanceof new class extends else return delete try break finally yield continue while false switch case
```

#### 24 words, 177 bytes

Without "true" and "false", which are apparently not keywords according to the question.

```js
void(function(){do{with({})if(typeof{}in this)throw{}instanceof new(class extends{}{})
else return{}
try{break}finally{yield}
continue
}while(delete{})})()
switch({}){case{}:{}}
```

Words:

```js
void function do with if typeof in this throw instanceof new class extends else return try break finally yield continue while delete switch case
```

Comment: (I accidentally deleted my comment instead of editing it, the contents were: "you can use delete{} in place of true/false, think (and just return nothing")

Comment: Ah, yes. I didn't pay much attention to that rule.

Comment: you can put `case ... :` or `default:` at the end (since `:` isn't allowed between keywords)

Comment: Ot you can end with `for(let _;0;);` for +2 words (but you can't use `case` anymore).

Comment: `switch({}){case{}:{}}` => `switch({}){case{}:;}`? Not know if `;` is sometimes necessary

Answer (score 7):

## <s>38</s> 39

```
class await {}
class g extends await {
 constructor() {
  super()
 }
}
switch ({}) {
 case function(){
  for (let in public)
  do with(package){
   try{break}catch(private){
   if(typeof this)
    throw static instanceof new (class extends await {})
   else{continue}}finally{debugger}
  }while(void protected)
  var implements
  return 
  yield delete interface
  const a=0
 }:
}
```

words from "super" to "const"

Golfed version:

```
class e{}class g extends e{constructor(){super()}}switch({}){case
function(){for(let in public)do with(package)try{break}catch(private){if(typeof
this)throw static instanceof new(class extends await{})
else{continue}}finally{debugger}while(void protected)
var implements
return 
yield delete interface
const a=0}:}
```

Comment: Is it now golfing time?

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token delete` when I try to run your answer in my Javascript console on Google Chrome, How can I test if your solution is valid?

Comment: @Ferrybig I use Firefox and it works fine. I can't install new version Chrome because of system

Comment: I get this error in Firefox `SyntaxError: yield expression is only valid in generators`

Comment: I use ff 52.7.2

Answer (score 4):

## 21 words

(not sure about `let` and `await`)

```js
var await=String, let=String;
switch (await) {
    case void typeof new await instanceof let in (function()
{do{try{return this
if((class extends{}{})){}else{break}}finally{(delete {})}}while(false)})():break;
}
```

Comment: `,` `=` and `;` are not allowed as separators.

Comment: They aren't being counted

Answer (score 4):

## <s>14</s> <s>15</s> 16 Words with no brackets or newline

```
!function(){if(0);else do throw yield new public in void typeof this instanceof class await extends function async(){}{};while(0)}
```

Thank Bergi for +1

Comment: Can you make it a generator function and throw in a `yield`?

Comment: I tried to figure out what this does, but my head started spinning. Could you post an explanation?

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token new` when I paste inside my javascript console

Comment: @Ferrybig, replace `function` with `function*`, so it will be recognized as a generator.

Answer (score 3):

## 43 words, 300 bytes

```
with(this)try{let protected}catch(package){if(delete yield)for(const interface in typeof public)do{throw implements instanceof private}while(static)else debugger}finally{switch(void new class extends function(){return}{export(){var await}import(){break}super(){continue}enum(){}case(){}}){default:0}}
```

More readably:

```
with(this)
    try {
        let protected
    } catch(package){
        if(delete yield)
            for(const interface in typeof public)
                do {
                    throw implements instanceof private
                } while(static)
        else
            debugger
    } finally {
        switch(
          void new class extends function(){return} {
              export(){var await}
              import(){break}
              super(){continue}
              enum(){}
              case(){}
          }
        ){
            default:0
        }
    }
```

I had to use the "reserved word as method name" to deal with

- `case` (since I had already used `default` with my `swtich`),
- `export` and `import` (since module-mode is always strict, which disqualifies `with`)
- `super` (since it must be followed by a property access or placed in a `constructor` function), and
- `enum` (which can never be used at all, being a reserved word with no grammatically-valid use)

Comment: My 39 solution shows `super` can appear in the beginning without being name, but too expensive

Answer (score 2):

## 28 Words without brackets, 234 Bytes

Putting identifier names as method definition names was too obvious ([for me at least](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49544859/how-many-reserved-keywords-can-you-put-together-that-could-be-in-production-code#comment86097608_49544859)), so I was looking for the longest consecutive distinct sequence of reserved words and whitespace in a code snippet.

I hope dead code after a `return` doesn't count as a loophole, but the code is still runnable if the used identifiers are declared.

```
function*_(){implements:{
let private
var public
return yield typeof static
delete protected
throw new interface in package
break implements
debugger
void this instanceof class await extends function async(){}{}
do
continue
while(0)}}
```

This exploits the fact that some of the future reserved keywords are only [considered invalid in ES5.1's strict mode](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.2) (apparently because engines didn't bother to block all of ES3's future reserved words so there was too much code using them out there on the web).

Similarly, the `async` and `await` tokens introduced in ES8 are only considered keywords in strict mode.

Comment: Can `break` and `continue` be there?

Comment: When I call the function, I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Undefined label 'implements'`, does your answer require a specific runtime?

Comment: @Nit Oops, I didn't actually call it, I only checked whether it's syntactically allowed (and then optimised prosaicism :D).

Comment: @l4m2 Oh, you're right, they can't but it's a runtime error so I didn't notice :-( Needed a bit of arbitrary reordering to work (and a block with the label).

Comment: @Bergi On Firefox it's syntax error on tio nodejs it's runtime